# Android: How to backup a database when the application gets closed?

Tags: android, service, backup, ondestroy

I am needing help to determine the right approach. I want to make a backup of an internal database to a location in the external storage every time the whole application gets interrupted or terminated/destroyed. I want to call this method from a central class called Main which extends Application. The reason for that is, that I need to use several activites and I want to call the backup Method only when needed (like described when the whole application gets destroyed or interrupted by another application). I try to avoid calling this backup method in every activity in their onPause() methods.

I thought about starting a service in the onCreate() method of the application, and starting the backup method when the service gets destroyed. But this won't help in the case of an interrupt, as far as I understood the logic behind services. And also the service doesn't seem to start. `startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackupService.class));` Furthermore I don't think it is a good approach to just use the onDestroy() method of a service, this is not what the service class is made for in my opinion.

So summarizing my Question, do you know a better way then using a service, or if not do you know how I should use the service to be able to call a backup only at the point when the whole app (and not only an activity) is interrupted or destroyed.

Comment: There is no concept in Android of "the whole app (and not only an activity) is interrupted or destroyed", other than when the process terminates.

Comment: But you can never be sure that the onTerminate() of an Application Class method really gets called.

Comment: You can guarantee that `onTerminate()` [will *never* be called on a production device](http://goo.gl/ZuhNU).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if your service "doesn't seem to start", you are probably doing something wrong.

To accomplish your goal make a backup of an internal database to a location in the external storage every time the whole application gets interrupted or terminated/destroyed:

There are three cases in general here.

If you want to do it in the activity layer:

1. To know when your application is crashed, you need to implement a custom handler to catch the uncaught exceptions.
2. To know when your activity is "interrupted", the only way is do it in onPause.
3. To know when your activity is "terminated", the only way is to do it in onDestroy.

This will require you to have a clear navigation and only do it in your "main activity", and all the other activity starts and comes back to it OR use a flag to indicate if the pause was caused by going to another activity.

If you want to do it in the service layer: (Your way of doing it onDestroy won't allow you to detect interrupted case since you will have to start service sticky to keep it running)

You will have to set up a flag on each activity onBind (you will have to bind it and unbind it) to know if it is a crash/interrupt/termination, which will complicate other part of your code.

To avoid running repetitive code, you will have to create a generic base class and extend your other activities from it.

Comment: Is your approach to have a MainActivity which is always called between every other Activities? So then just using the onPause(), onDestroy() method of this MainActivity. But isn't it quite complicate as well to handle the navigation from activity A to activity B not directly but always via the mainActivity. Isn't it better to have a direct navigation between the activities and using an Application class for global issues, like the backup at the end? Or am I just thinking to much in C# paradigmens, where I originally come from.

Comment: Use the flag as suggested by Raghav and use a service to catch uncaught exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I use this approach to play background music in one of my games, but I guess it works in this scenario as well.

Use a boolean flag to indicate whether or not your app is launching another part of your app.

```
boolean movingInApp = false;
....
movingInApp = true;
Intent intent...
.....
public void onPause() {
    if(!movingInApp) {
        //start service
    }
}

public void onResume() {
    movingInApp = false;
    //Stop service
}
```

By setting the value of `movingInApp` to `true` before launching any intent etc, you can prevent your app from starting the service. Remember to set it to false again later in your `onResume()` method. If the system makes your app go to the background, this will be false, and your service will be started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I understand your answer right, then you start the service (when !movingInApp) from an activity. This would mean I would have to write the same code in all activities I use. I wanted to avoid this, that's why I use the application class (with no support of e.g. onPause (as far as I know)), do you know something that might help me in this case?

Comment: You must use the Activity callbacks since, as you rightly say, there is no onPause() or onDestroy() in the Application class.  But don't rely on this for consistency as it is perfectly legitimate for Android to kill your activity with no further callbacks.

Comment: @Elementary You can have one `BaseActivity` extending Activity with this code, and have all your other Activities subclass that one

Comment: @Raghav Sood You mean all the subclasses should inherit from this BaseActivity? Could be a good idea to start with, I will think a bit more about that. Thank you.

Comment: @Elementary Yup. That's exactly what I mean. By doing that, you need to implement the code only once in the BaseActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u have all of your activities extend a base activity which in turn extend the android activity class
I  the base activity have backupDB method in the onPause
Therefore u dont have to put it in every activity pause method